# Raw Material Audit Report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Please review screen shot. [image]

```
No          RM Weight            Weight           Remaining RM weight


1           1000                 50                   800

2            800                100                   700

3            700                 50                   650

4            650                300                   350

5            350                 50                   300
```

We want help to create the report given in image where we are using the formula:

> Remaining RM Weight = RM Weight - Weight

Please help me by giving logic and syntax for the same.

Comment: I've embedded the picture for you. Please use `>` to format a blockquote, and `␣␣␣␣indent four spaces` to format code in the future.

Comment: ok But How to do in Crystal report please give logic...!

Comment: What is the issue now? Is your formula not working?

Comment: issue is that how to how calculate Remaining RM weight value

Comment: i have don't have idea how to store previous row value

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understand below is the solution.

1. Place the `RM Weight` and `Weight` in detail section.
2. Create formula `@Remaining RM weight` and write below code:

   ```
   RM Weight - Weight
   ```
3. Place `@Remaining RM weight` after the two fields.

Let me know if this is not your requirement.